# Each snowflake is beautiful but some are "pretty"

Tags: pattern, visual, geometry

Let's define "snowflakey" pattern as

1. Regular polygon
2. surrounded by other regular polygons
3. number of surrounding polygons equals to a number of angles of polygon in the middle

Here are two groups of snowflakeys:

[image]

Each snowflakey in the left group I consider "pretty" and each snowflakey in the right group I consider "not pretty".

What is "pretty" snowflakey? Would I consider pretty all snowflakies on the right side taken together?

Comment: Hi! It's my first contribution to puzzling stackexchange. It's intended for my D&D table, but I also decided to share it with you. Perhaps, it's simple by local standards - I intend to post harder version of puzzle with same idea later.

Comment: What is the puzzle here - to figure out the criteria for being "pretty"?

Comment: Yes. Rephrased text to be more clear.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that a pretty snowflake is...

> One where the total number of sides is a multiple of four

... and that if we consider all of the snowflakes on the right...

> They are pretty as there is a total of 144 sides.

Comment: Yep, that's correct

Comment: Some observations that might be fun: any snowflakey where the outer shapes are triangles/heptagons etc. is pretty. Any snowflakey where the inner shape is a quadrilateral/octagon etc. is pretty.